# How to execute shell commands from the application

Tags: android, adb, sh

I am trying to run below command through an app, but it's not working. I get no `Exception`. I'm using an emulator.

```
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
 process = rt.exec( new String[]{"/system/bin/sh","-c","echo \" \" > /data/xyz.txt"});
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Seems like something that should be forbidden for security reasons.

Comment: @john but in emulator it should work right,since emulator is by default rooted

Comment: @john Is it possible from the application or not?

Comment: @john not getting any exception when I run above code in emulator but the outcome is nothing

Comment: See [this](https://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=2457).

Comment: @john but then how to execute echo \" \" > /data/xyz.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by changing the SELinux permissive mode

$ adb shell su -c setenforce 0